# Get AWS SSM Parameter without aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I would like to retrieve AWS SSM Parameters in a Docker image in the `entrypoint.sh` file and inject the params into env vars.

I can successfully do this by `apk add aws-cli`, but this will bloat the docker image by quite a bit as it downloads the entire AWS SDK.

The next option is to try to construct a proper curl request and handle all the auth information, but it's not as simple as passing in your `AWS_ACCESS_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` and gets a bit involved.

Is there an easy way to just get AWS SSM Parameters without having to install the aws-cli?

Comment: Are you using ECS or EKS? and how are you provisioning the resources i.e. CDK, CloudFormation?

Comment: Raw EC2 in a Docker container using watchtower. EC2 instanced has an IAM role so I don't need to explicitly define creds in the env. Using ECR to store the image. Using terraform to provision an infra and CircleCI for the deployment automation